# How to transfer USDT on polygon chain from one EOA account to another EOA account

Tags: polygon, erc20

I believe I have to use transferFrom function of ERC20. But I didn't get success.
I also want to know will this approach show volume on chain for my contract address or I need to change the flow to EOA->smart contract->EOA.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
pragma solidity ^0.8;

interface IERC20 {
    function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) external returns     (bool);
    function approve(address spender, uint256 value) external returns (bool);
    function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint256 value) external returns (bool);
    function balanceOf(address account) external view returns (uint256);
}

contract MyContract {

    function sendUSDT(address _from, address _to, uint256 _amount) external returns (bool) {
        IERC20 usdt = IERC20(address(0x2F7b97837F2D14bA2eD3a4B2282e259126A9b848));// mumbai testnet
        return usdt.transferFrom(_from, _to, _amount);
    }
    
    function approve(address spender, uint256 value) external returns(bool) {
        IERC20 usdt = IERC20(address(0x2F7b97837F2D14bA2eD3a4B2282e259126A9b848));
        return usdt.approve(spender, value);
    }

    function balanceOf(address account) external view returns (uint256){
        IERC20 usdt = IERC20(address(0x2F7b97837F2D14bA2eD3a4B2282e259126A9b848));
        return usdt.balanceOf(account);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

> *I believe I have to use `transferFrom` function of ERC20*

Correct. But before that, your contract needs to be approved by the user to spend their tokens. So it's a two-transaction process.

1st transaction:
**The user needs to execute the `approve()` function on the token contract directly** - not through your contract. Passing your contract address (the spender) as the first argument, and the max amount they approve you to spend as the second argument.

2nd transaction: Only then you're able `transferFrom()` the user's tokens to another address through your contract.

---

The way your contract is written now, you're actually giving the `spender` approval to spend `value` of `usdt` tokens that are owned by your contract.

Comment: What if I want to transfer USDT from an EOA to my smart contract. The signer of this transaction must be EOA. And handke all this stuff in solidity inside contract itself

Comment: Then the user can invoke the `transfer()` function on the `USDT` contract directly. Disadvantage of this approach is that your contract (the token receiver) doesn't get notified in any way about the transfer.